# Ruby on Rails Activerecord - id в модели перепутаны

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Дело обстоит в Ruby on Rails 4.2.0 на Ruby 2.1.0.

Есть следующая миграция:

```
class CreateStateTemplates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :state_templates do |t|

      t.string :name

      t.references :next
      t.references :prev

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

...такая модель:

```
class StateTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :prev, :class_name => "StateTemplate", :foreign_key => "prev_id"
  belongs_to :state_template, :class_name => "StateTemplate", :foreign_key => "prev_id"
  has_one :next, :class_name => "StateTemplate", :foreign_key => "next_id"
  belongs_to :state_template, :class_name => "StateTemplate", :foreign_key => "next_id"

end
```

Если выполнить следующее:

```
StateTemplate.find(1).update(:next => StateTemplate.find(2))
StateTemplate.find(2).update(:next => StateTemplate.find(3), :prev => StateTemplate.find(1))
StateTemplate.find(3).update(:next => StateTemplate.find(4), :prev => StateTemplate.find(2))
StateTemplate.find(4).update(:next => StateTemplate.find(5), :prev => StateTemplate.find(3))
StateTemplate.find(5).update(:prev => StateTemplate.find(4))
```

Происходит нечто странное. Получение одного StateTemplate в консоли показывает следующее:

```
2.1.0 :007 > StateTemplate.find(2)
  StateTemplate Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "state_templates".* FROM "state_templates" WHERE "state_templates"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => #<StateTemplate id: 2, name: "two", next_id: 1, prev_id: 3, created_at: "2017-07-22 11:51:30", updated_at: "2017-07-22 11:51:30">
```

Что неверно, `next_id` должен быть 3. При этом метод `next` показывает следующее:

```
2.1.0 :008 > StateTemplate.find(2).next
  StateTemplate Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "state_templates".* FROM "state_templates" WHERE "state_templates"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  StateTemplate Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "state_templates".* FROM "state_templates" WHERE "state_templates"."next_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["next_id", 2]]
 => #<StateTemplate id: 3, name: "three", next_id: 2, prev_id: 4, created_at: "2017-07-22 11:51:30", updated_at: "2017-07-22 11:51:30">
```

А это уже верно.

Почему id в записи перепутаны местами, но получение ассоциированных записей при этом работает верно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не удаляйте — вопрос хороший.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что вы перепутали `has_one` и `belongs_to`. Для обеих сторон.

К тому же, сейчас у вас дважды определена ассоциация `state_template`, работать будет только последнее из этих определений. Уже это указывает, что что-то с определениями не так.

**Посмотрим на `next`.**

Проблема тут:

```
has_one :next, :class_name => "StateTemplate", :foreign_key => "next_id"
belongs_to :state_template, :class_name => "StateTemplate", :foreign_key => "next_id"
```

Это должно быть:

```
belongs_to :next, :class_name => "StateTemplate"
```

И симметрично для `prev`.

---

#### Что происходит?

Вы, наверное, думаете, что эти две строчки ведут себя примерно одинаково:

```
StateTemplate.find(1).update(:next => StateTemplate.find(2))
StateTemplate.find(1).update(:next_id => 2)
```

Но из ваших ассоциаций следует, что первая строчка изменяет **второй** объект (который в аргументе), ставя ему `next_id = 1`. Несмотря на то, что обновляете вы, казалось бы, первый.

Вы неправильно определили ассоциацию `next`.

- Сейчас ассоциированный — объект, у которого `next_id` равен `id` владельца. [**Ибо `has_one`.**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one)
- А хотели вы наоборот: получить объект, `id` которого равен `next_id` владельца. [**Это `belongs_to`.**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)

Запись, которая хранит в себе ключ ассоциированного объекта, относится к нему через `belongs_to`. А вот `has_one` и `has_many` хранят ключ не "в себе", а в ассоциированных объектах.

"Минус на минус даёт плюс". Апдейты сделали совсем не то, что вы подумали. И поиск ассоциированных записей работает не так, как вы хотите. Но оба пользуются одним определением и в сумме они работают верно: запись определённой записи в `next` действительно заставляет метод `next` у этого объекта возвращать эту запись.